# How can I apply repositories from a remote script plugin to the pluginManagement block?

Tags: gradle

I would like to use the incubating [`plugins` block](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) to `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "0.4.1"
}
```

By default, this pulls plugins from the Gradle plugin portal. However, we have a requirement in our organization that we need to use our internal Artifactory repository, rather than the public Gradle plugin portal or a similar repository.

I see that the [`pluginManagement` block](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management) can be used to specify repositories, by adding the following to `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.example.com/"
        }
    }
}
```

We have several repositories, along with some credential logic, so in the past, we have just had this all bundled in a script plugin at a remote URL, then accessed it in our `build.gradle` file like so:

```
apply from: "https://shared.example.com/repositories.gradle"
```

The `repositories.gradle` file currently contains a `repositories {}` block that has several repositories.

Is there any way that I can apply this remote script plugin to the `pluginManagement` block? I tried going into my `settings.gradle` file and doing it this way:

```
pluginManagement {
    apply from: "https://shared.example.com/repositories.gradle"
}
```

However, I got the error message `Could not find method repositories() for arguments`. Is there some other way that I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you apply the external Gradle script in a specific context (e.g. `pluginManagement`), it won't be executed in this context. The `apply` method is implemented by the `Settings` object, so it is chosen as target object by default. You can try to delegate the script to another object by using the `to` parameter in the map you pass to the `apply` method:

```
apply to: pluginManagement, from: "https://shared.example.com/repositories.gradle"
```